# find length of visable/hidden list items faster

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a jquery newbie and have been adding alert timestamps into my html file to find what lines of code are making things slow.  I have found the main bottleneck and am looking for help to know how to change these 2 lines to be faster.

My html file has about 600 list items in it.  If the file only had 6 list items, the speed would be fine.

```
    var visablecount = 0;
    var totalcount = 0;
    for (var key in checkArray) {
        if (checkArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            $tmp = key.split(" ");
            $.each($tmp, function(i, val4) {            
                //*********next two lines are the most slow lines*********
                visablecount = $itemsToFilter.children("li."+val4+":visible").length;
                totalcount = $itemsToFilter.children("li."+val4+":hidden").length + visablecount;
                //********************************************************
                $("#labelID"+val4).text(val4 +" (" + visablecount + "/" + totalcount + ")");
                if ($this.is(":checked")) {
                    if ($('.' + val4 + '').is(":visible") == true) {                            
                        $('.filters input[value=' + val4 + ']').attr('checked', true);                          
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but if you are using a browser that supports console.log() [Chrome, Safari and some others] I suggest you use them over alerts - you can output a lot of useful data without annoying popups interrupting the execution of the javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM updates are the slowest, so if you can store them and insert in one go, at the end, it would be much faster.

Your  `$("#labelID"+val4).text(...)` is probably the slowest part of the code. Build this up as a string and insert it once, out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I have made couple of minor changes. Please try this out and let me know how it goes,

```
var visablecount = 0;
var totalcount = 0;
var childVisibleLi = $itemsToFilter.children("li:visible");
var childHiddenLi = $itemsToFilter.children("li:hidden");

for (var key in checkArray) {
   // if (checkArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) { //<-- You don't need it when you iterate over key
        $tmp = key.split(" ");
        $.each($tmp, function(i, val4) {            
            //*********next two lines are the most slow lines*********
            visablecount = childVisibleLi.filter("."+val4).length;
            totalcount = childHiddenLi.filter("."+val4).length + visablecount;
            //********************************************************

            $("#labelID"+val4).text(val4 +" (" + visablecount + "/" + totalcount + ")");
            if ($this.is(":checked")) {

         //  below if can be changed.. use filter instead of directly using .class

                if ($('.' + val4 + '').is(":visible") == true) {                            
                    $('.filters input[value=' + val4 + ']').attr('checked', true);                          
                }
            }                
        });
    //}
}
```

Comment: This was helpful but I did not use it.  I noticed that the values in the loop were not unique.  I added code to only work with unique values.  This made the 2 slow lines run a lot faster since they are not called as often.

Answer (score 0):

Looking just at your slow lines, you can avoid performing the `.children(...)` selector twice. Instead, cache the result of `.children(...)` and sidestep the need to perform an addition as follows:

```
//********* replacement for the slow lines ********
$foo = $itemsToFilter.children("li." + val4);
visablecount = $foo.is(":visible").length;
totalcount = $foo.length;
//*************************************************
```

Note: $foo should be declared outside the loop as per `visablecount` and `totalcount`.